# EXISTS without a second table join (self join)

Tags: sql, oracle, exists

I have a table of following structure

Parent ID number, Child ID number, Address varchar2(100)

I want to write a SQL that pulls all records by searching on Address field.

Only twist is, i would like all records of the {parent id} combination if even one of the {child} had a {address} criteria match.

I know we would code this in say this way,

```
SELECT parent_id, child_id, address
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE EXISTS
          (SELECT 1
             FROM mytable t2
            WHERE t.parent_id = t2.parent_id
                  AND address LIKE :p_search_criteria);
```

But is there any better solution than this? Key is that we are searching within the same table that we are retrieving from...

This is Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with analytic functions, if you wanted:

```
SELECT parent_id, child_id, address
FROM (select t.*,
             max(case when address LIKE :p_search_criteria then 1 else 0 end) over      
                 (partition by parent_id) as addrflag
      from mytable t
     ) t
WHERE addrflag = 1;
```

If you have the right indexes, then the `exists` version might still be faster.

Comment: thanks Gordon, i am going to give it a try to see if it is any better. So you think Analytical function in this case is even worse than adding a whole 'new' table to the mix? I agree it all "depends" and must be measured to be established. I was just running crazy and was looking for any other option. This is just that, thanks!

Comment: The performance question is very open on this query.  It depends on the number of children that parents have, the overall size of the data, the nature of the search criteria, and existing indexes.  The best solution might incorporate Oracle Full Text indexing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Oracle in itself, but using standard SQL queries, couldn't you do the following?

```
SELECT t.parent_id, t.child_id, t.address
FROM mytable t LEFT JOIN
mytable t2 on t.parent_id=t2.parent_id
where t2.address LIKE :p_search_criteria;
```

Comment: I could except that all i wanted to was NOT to add a second table to the query ... and hence the join